# Can IOS Simulator run a dart file that is not named main.dart?

Tags: xcode, flutter, dart, ios-simulator

I am currently trying to run an app where main.dart and screen.dart are in the same directory. However, when I test screen.dart using the simulator, it runs the main.dart

Similarly, when I move screen.dart to a separate directory and try running it there, my terminal says it cannot find main.dart

Is there anyway to fix this or am I going about this the wrong way? I am trying to call screen.dart from the main.dart so I assumed it should be in the same directory. I've tried looking online but I am unsure if I am wording my question right and thought I'll ask here. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In flutter you can use any file as main file just use `flutter run -t <file-path>` so to run screen.dart just use `flutter run -t screen.dart` if screen.dart is directly inside lib folder, if not provide the relative path from lib folder.